# Handling URLs of new, mobile-friendly pages (Using Struts 1)

Tags: java, struts-1

My site (which uses Struts 1) is getting ready to launch mobile-friendly versions of about six pages. I could use some advice on what the new URLS should be.
My first thought on how to do it would be to define new mappings under the existing path in struts-config.xml, then detect the presence of a mobile browser in the relevant Action class and have that forward to the new .jsp files when appropriate; this way the URLS would be the same for the mobile and "regular" versions of the pages. However, most sites I've seen with mobile versions seem to either use a subdomain (m.example.com) or have something specific in the URL (www.example.com/mobile/...) and this made me wonder if there is a good reason to have something in the url. A subdomain is not feasible for us, but customized urls would be.
If altered urls is the way to go, how should the Struts configuration be set up? Should I define completely different paths that use the same underlying Action class?
I don't know a lot about mobile development (we actually outsourced the creation of the actual pages) so I really don't know what's considered the best practice.

Comment: Some mobile users may have valid reasons for wanting the slower but fully functional original page.  I personally prefer to be directed to the mobile site but have a way around that when it inevitably fails to deliver some bit of functionality that I know is available on the non-mobile site.  Be sure you provide a way to switch between the two sites for your mobile users.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I am keeping that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you have sounds perfectly reasonable to me, especially if URLs are important to your application (such as to enable bookmarking, do url params processing etc)

The only reason you may want to encode m or mobile in the url path or domain name would be to not have to detect the mobile client for every request (the domain name/context path will leverage the container (Java EE or other) to automatically pull the correct assets for mobile browsers (jsp etc)